# making a simple javascript event with input from user

Tags: javascript, html, events

```js
window.onload= button;

function termFunction () {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
    var term= textInput.value;

    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML= term.value;
}

function button () {
    var button = document.getElementById("button"); 
    button.onclick= termFunction(); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "review2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Term: <input type = "text" id = "list">
    <input type = "button" id = "button" value= "submit">
</body>
</html>
```

I trying to make someone type in the text box and it prints out onto the HTML page. but I don't know why it wouldn't work.

Comment: `var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");` your input id is actually `list`

Comment: `button.onclick = termFunction()` sgould probably be `button.onclick = termFunction`, since you don't want to run `termFunction` immediately

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu but when i do that term is null

Comment: Where is your `#textInput` element? And where do you want to output your user input? Based on the suggestions you are likely to be reading from and then writing to the same input element, which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error when you are reading property of the id which is not present

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

**Solution**

Since you are reading value of the id **textInput** which is not present in body see this line

> var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");

If you want to get the value of user input replac id  with **list**

> var textInput = document.getElementById("list");

**Final Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src = "review2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Term: <input type = "text" id = "list">
<input type = "button" id = "button" value= "submit">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
window.onload= button;

function termFunction () {
var textInput = document.getElementById("list").value;


document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= textInput;
}

function button () {
var button = document.getElementById("button"); 
button.onclick= termFunction(); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your input has an id = "list". therefore, must use

```
var textInput = document.getElementById ("list");
```

as it does not make sense to modify the content of an input

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML= term.value;
```

I think you have to check the ids of your HTML elements

Update:
i add an example:

```js
function termFunction () {
    var textInput = document.getElementById("list").value;
   if(textInput)
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML= textInput;
}
```

```html
 Term: <input type = "text" id="list">
<input type = "button" id = "button" value= "submit" onclick="termFunction()">
    
<br /><br />
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: i edit my answer by adding un example of code that runs